# Xcode allocation problems with UIImagaView keep growing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I load alot of images in my image gallery and in my thumbnail gallery, every time i press a button (section) i replace the images with the right seciont's images, all ok since the 6th-7th time i do this my app crash.
So i tried build with allocation tool and i see allocation memory growing up every time i press the button! i've been aspected to see a stack memory allocation not a growing one with
initWithContentOfFile.
What am i doing wrong?

```
for (UIView *view in [scroller subviews]) {

    [view removeFromSuperview];


}
for (UIView *view in [thumbnail subviews]) {

    [view removeFromSuperview];


}


for (int i=1; i<numeroimg+1; i++) {
    UIImageView *imagen = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                                               [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",sezione,i]
                                                                ofType:@"jpg"]]]autorelease];
    imagen.frame = CGRectMake((i-1)*1024, 0, 1024, 704);

    [scroller addSubview:imagen];

    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*210, 30, 200, 150)]autorelease];
    [button setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",sezione,i]
                       ofType:@"jpg"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pagina:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i;
    [thumbnail addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: nop had to start the work with an older version of xcode so i couldn't put it

Comment: you can convert a project to ARC there is a WWDC 2011 video on it, just search the apple dev resources.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

You're using `+alloc` to create an image:

```
UIImageView *imagen = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...
```

but you never release `imagen`.

Comment: even if i remove autorelease and add [imagen release]; and [button release]; it's still growing

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually drain the autorelease pool

```
@autoreleasepool{
UIImageView *imagen = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                                               [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",sezione,i]
                                                                ofType:@"jpg"]]]autorelease];
    imagen.frame = CGRectMake((i-1)*1024, 0, 1024, 704);

    [scroller addSubview:imagen];

    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*210, 30, 200, 150)]autorelease];
    [button setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",sezione,i]
                       ofType:@"jpg"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pagina:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i;
    [thumbnail addSubview:button];
}
```